# RFIDRW-E-232 can't understand commands from Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, rfid

Hello I have some problems with communication with this animal RFID tag reader.
I am using Rasperry Pi, Java and PI4J.
I am sending commands to the reader according to documentation: http://www.priority1design.com.au/rfidrw-e-usb.pdf

I tried to switch led on/off, get the firmware version and many other commands. I still get the answer 0x00 (Command not understood.)

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Serial serial = SerialFactory.createInstance();

    try {
        serial.open(Serial.DEFAULT_COM_PORT, 9600);
        serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
                try {
                    String data = event.getData();
                    byte[] array = data.getBytes("US-ASCII");
                    String s = "";
                    System.out.println("Read: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        s = s + String.format("%02X ", array[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(s);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                }
            }
        });
        //byte [] data = "VER".getBytes("US-ASCII");
        String data = "VER";
        //byte [] data = {(byte) 0x56,(byte) 0x45,(byte) 0x52};

        serial.write(data);
        //serial.write("\r");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        serial.close();
    }
}
```

Do you know where can be the problem?
Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve your problem? I am, like you, trying to communicate with a RFIDRW-E-232 using Java. I am developing an Android app for this though. I only get the byte values 1 and 96 which I dont know what to make of. Unlike you I have lots of code that claims an interface and then uses two endpoints to read and write.
I have also tried doing the same in .Net but I get the exact same result.

Comment: Yes I did. I had to switch RX and TX pins. But I guess that will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but when I looked at the [pi4j Serial example page](http://pi4j.com/example/serial.html)

it suggests this, I wonder if you have tried disabling COM port being a console?

```
    // !! ATTENTION !!
    // By default, the serial port is configured as a console port 
    // for interacting with the Linux OS shell.  If you want to use 
    // the serial port in a software program, you must disable the 
    // OS from using this port.  Please see this blog article by  
    // Clayton Smith for step-by-step instructions on how to disable 
    // the OS console for this port:
    // http://www.irrational.net/2012/04/19/using-the-raspberry-pis-serial-port/
```

There're also seems to exist a utility for switching port from console https://github.com/lurch/rpi-serial-console

Comment: Yes I have everything disabled